# Schwarz Lemma proof question about inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation, maximum-principle, holomorphic-functions

The proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Proof)  has the following inequality:

[image]

But shouldn't it be the case that, by the Maximum Modulus Principle, $|f(z_r)|=1$, not just $\le 1$, since we are initially given that $|f(z)|\le 1$, and so it must achieve $1$ somewhere - namely, on the boundary of the disk. Moreover, how do we know that $f(z)$ is even defined on the boundary of the disk?

In addition, how do we know that $f'(0)\ne 0$?

Comment: It is only assumed that $|f|$ is *bounded* by one. Take $f(z) = z/2$ as an example. Also it does not matter if $f'(0) = 0$ or not.

Comment: I see. So the $\le 1$ does not necessarily mean that $f(z)$ must achieve $1$ somewhere.

Comment: Indeed. Also note that that part of the proof considers the function on a *smaller* disk, on which the maximum *cannot* be $1$.

Comment: More simply: $f$ maps the unit disk into itself, that implies $|f(z_r)| < 1$.